# Java heap space,AIR 18

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I am working on an IOS application, using Flashdevelop and AIR SDK version 18. I got the Java heap space error while compiling the project.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Modify the jvm.config - I have not tried this, because there is not such file in AIR SDK.
2. Modify the adt.bat file -Xms1024 -Xmx1024 - I tried it but not working
3. Modify the mxmlc.bat, but like adt.bat - not working

Any solution? I'll be grateful for any ideas! Please keep in mind I cannot divide the resources and the code - I must pack them together.

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows? And assuming that you have thousands of resources (sound, pics, etc...) in that project.

Comment: 64bit,more than 100 of media

Comment: You can try setting the java options in adt.bat even higher: -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m . This is a old known problem, mainly Windows based... we worked around it once by using OS-X for builds...

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this problem today and wanted to let people know that this can be caused by programmer error...

I had just set up a simple parallax background for my game.  It worked fine when the player moved a short distance but I needed to test a long distance.  In my game the player moves right automatically until he encounters an enemy so to get him to walk a long distance I simply had to move the enemy further away.  I set enemy x to 999999, compiled... and got the Java Heap Space error.  I have no idea why that would cause me to run out of memory (I don't really understand how display objects work) but restoring the enemy's position and restarting FlashDevelop fixed the problem.